# How to pass a String variable containing value with hyphens as a java script function parameter

Tags: javascript

Hi I am a newbie to java script. Have issues in passing the string variable whose value contains hyphen as function parameter. Fire bug throws an error saying 'identifier starts immediately after numeric literal'

I am using flexigrid to display data. In each row have placed an image. On click of that image a java script function should be called. Setting up of flexigrid record content is done in java as below,

```
record.put("view","<img src='images/ic_text_document.png' onclick='view_content("+objid+")'/> ");
```

Value of the varible objid is something like this c2692d22-a407-4d38-85ee-5c16f25bcce7. 
Firebug throws identifier starts immediately after numeric literal' error by pointing at the 14th digit (in the above example at 4).

Tried passing the variable with different combination of quotes as suggested in other posts but dint work. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should quote the `objid` value, like

```
record.put("view","<img src='images/ic_text_document.png' onclick='view_content(\""+objid+"\")'/> ");
```

Comment: I have tried that. In that case it does not evaluate the objid instead uses objid itself as the value.

Comment: What is **objid itself**? Does the `"objid"` string become the parameter or is `objid` something different than a string???

Comment: Its just that I was escaping the quotes in a wrong way. By escaping it in the way suggested worked.. Thank you for the quick and timely response

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the objid before generating the html, and unescape when using the value in the javascript.

**OR** do something like this......

```
record.put("view","<img src='images/ic_text_document.png' onclick='view_content("+ COUNTER + ")'/><div style='display:none' id='objid"+ COUNTER + "'>" + objid + "</div> ");
```

where counter is just a different number/value for each obj/objid.
and in js:

```
function view_content(objidcounter){    
var real_objid = document.getElementById('objid' + objidcounter).innerText;
...
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when it render it is showing up as

```
view_content(FOOBARSTRING)
```

You need quotes in there.

```
record.put("view","<img src='images/ic_text_document.png' onclick='view_content(\""+objid+"\")'/> ");
```

Ideally you would not be adding the onclick handlers in the html markup directly.

Comment: I have tried that. In that case it does not evaluate the objid instead uses objid itself as the value.

Comment: You need to show more code since what you said is objid is a string with dashes, but now you are saying it is doing something else.

Comment: Its just that I was escaping the quotes in a wrong way. By escaping it in the way suggested  worked.. Thank you for the quick and timely response...